# parsing il2cpp_ghidra.h from il2cppdumper in ghidra fails

Tags: il2cpp, ghidra

when i use il2cppdumper, get il2cpp.h, then run il2cpp_header_to_ghidra.py and after that trying to open il2cpp_ghidra.h with ghidra (File > Parse C source > add il2cpp_ghidra.h to list > parse program) i'm getting error in il2cpp_ghidra.h:

```
Error: Encountered " " * " "* "" at line 9916, column 37.
Was expecting one of:
<VOLATILE> ...
"static" ...
<CONST> ...
<CDECL> ...
"__declspec" ...
"__readableTo" ...
etc...
```

9916 line in il2cpp_ghidra.h is

```
struct System_Reflection_RuntimeConstructorInfo_o* m_serializationCtor;
```

i use newest versions of both ghidra and il2cppdumper.
maybe downgrading to some other version of the ghidra or il2cppdumper will help? (i don't know to which version)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when using a default parsing configuration. I fixed it, by creating my own parsing config with empty "Include Paths" and "Parse Options" and selecting the il2cpp_ghidra.h file in "Source files to parse". Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).